# PostgreSQL database query with parametrized column input

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, select, where-clause

I am trying to make a database query with python and postgreSQL which takes user input from both a dropdown list and a text field. The input from the dropdown is supposed to determine which column to query for the text input. It works as needed without the use of the dropdown menu input  but returns none when using it.

```
str = request.args.get("str")
type = request.args.get("type")
query = "%" + str + "%"
books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE :type ILIKE (:query)", {"type": type, "query": query}).fetchmany(100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a column name as a parameter to the query. What happens with your code is that Postres understands parameter `:type` as a literal string, and tries to match it against the other parameter. This is not what you want.

So you would need to concatenate the column name into the query string. This means that you need to perform proper validation on application side *before* that, otherwise you are exposing your code to SQL injection; I would expect that you should be able to validate the column name against a fixed list of values.

```
str = request.args.get("str")
type = request.args.get("type")
# !! perform parameter validation !!
query = "%" + str + "%"
books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE " + type + " ILIKE :query", {"query": query}).fetchmany(100)
```

Side note: `ILIKE` is an operator, not a function - you don't need to surround the right operand with parentheses.